# Eclipse Indigo freezes on 'Open Type' search

Tags: eclipse

When I'm trying to search for a Java class with Ctrl-shift-T (Open Type popup), Eclipse freezes when I'm typing 1 character. It usually takes about 8 seconds to 'unfreeze', but sometimes it won't come back at all.. When it freezes, I see that the eclipse process takes about 1Gig of mem and the CPU is about 100%!

I've tried creating a new workspace, adjusting the eclipse.ini (perm size, different memory values), starting with -clean and at last reinstall the whole IDE. Nothing helps..

My eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
768m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-server
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xmn128m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss2m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
```

I'm using the following plugins: JRebel and m2e. I'm desperate for a solution because this problems causes me a great deal of time loss.

System: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit, 4GB mem, Intel core i7 860 @ 2.8 Ghz.

Hope somebody knows a solution. Thank you  for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue... i think.
It's related to this:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384315

It's an issue with GTK. try to remove libgail18. The issue is resolved, So I think it will be in the next maintenance version.

Answer (score 3):

I did not want to remove libgail18 package entirely, because there are too many things that depend on it, so I simply renamed `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgailutil.so.18.0.1` to `libgailutil.so.18.0.1.OFF`.

This makes Eclipse fast again and gives me the option to re-enable the library if I need it for something else.

Answer (score 1):

[Not an answer, but I'm not able to comment on your question]

I suffer from the same problem where Open Type hangs Eclipse for prolonged periods, typically around 2 minutes making Eclipse unusable. This only happened about 2 months after using this machine daily as a development machine.

Unfortunately I haven't managed to get to the bottom of it either. Of note I'm also running an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit machine (8GB memory, Intel® Xeon(R) CPU X3450 @ 2.67GHz × 4).

> java version "1.6.0_24" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1)
>   (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu3) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed
>   mode)

I've also tried the Oracle JDK, 1.6.0.30. It didn't help.

I've tried installing many different versions of Eclipse:

- 3.6
- 3.7 (From Eclipse.org & installed via apt)
- 4.2
- Spring Source
  All of which suffered from the same problem.

Trashing my .workspace & .eclipse directories and having no custom plugins didn't help.

What did help was creating a new user account on my box. Unfortunately this also only worked for about a month. This does give me hope that there is some cache or file in my home drive that I can could delete to work around the problem, but I haven't found it. I'm now faced with creating another user or getting to the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Hmm oke, so creating a new user helps, didn't know that.. Still hoping for a better, permanent solution though:)! So if you come accross some solution, please post it in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

When faced with similar issue on Windows, adding clean option to 'startWCToolkit.bat' helped. I'm sure there should be similar script on Ubuntu too. An excerpt of file:

```
"rationalsdp.exe" –clean   -showlocation -debug
```